# python udp client -sending hex values

Tags: python, character-encoding

i have a udp python client witch i wand to send hex values to udp server

here is my code :

```
import socket as socket_library

if __name__ == "__main__":
ipv4_local_host = "192.168.56.1"
server_port = 35970
addr = (ipv4_local_host, server_port)

bufferSize = 4096

# Create a UDP socket at client side
socket_client = socket_library.socket(family=socket_library.AF_INET, 
type=socket_library.SOCK_DGRAM)

#data = "\xF1\xF2\xF3"
#data = "\x0F\x01\x02\x03"
#data = "\x1F\x1E\x0D\xE3"
data="\xCA\xFE"

data = data.encode("utf-8")

socket_client.sendto(bytes(data), addr)code here
```

i am using hurculis terminal to receive the udp communication and  the terminals shows wrong value , what i am expecting to see in the terminal is :
0xCA 0XFE hexadecimal

but the terminal shows   :
{C3}{8A}{C3}{BE}

i guess it something have to do with the encoding , how can i fix my code so the terminal will show the right values 0xCA 0XFE

Answer (score 1):

the `utf-8` encoding will actually transform your hex code-points, in the text string, to its multi-byte encoding, which features `\xC3` as one prefix for a 2-byte code.

If you want your bytes raw, write bytestrings instead of text: prefix the strings with `b`, like `data = b"\xF1\xF2\xF3"`, and do not make the call to the `.encode(...)` method at all.

Also, you can save on typing by using the `bytes.fromhex` constructor: it will take the characters 0-9a-fA-F themselves, ignore whytespace, and build the bytes object for you without the need for all the `\x` prefixing:

`data = bytes.fromhex("F1 F2 F3")`